# how to embed Camtasia swf in HTML?

Tags: flash, html, camtasia

I succeed to embed the Camtasia swf files in html using SWFObject, but I faced a problem that it's not working in Chrome, but it's working OK in IE9 and Firefox.
I found an answer for that, just to disable the built-in Shockwave Flash (version 11.3.31.227) in Chrome, BUT I need an answer in code .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that chrome browser loads external javascript asynchronously.

So at the time swfoject is invoked, "swfobject" in null.

and refer a following artice:

http://dougr.net/2011/07/05/automatically-setting-swf-object-focus/

http://www.therealtimeweb.com/index.cfm/2012/1/30/swf-load-issues-chrome